# Why does datetime.now().isoformat() return an invalid isoformat string according to time.fromisoformat()?

Tags: python, python-datetime, isodate

Running Python 3.8.10, came across this today:

```
from datetime import datetime, time
time.fromisoformat(datetime.now().isoformat())
```

Results in:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> ValueError: Invalid isoformat string: '2021-09-02T17:16:49.330690'

Why is an isoformat string created by the datetime.datetime module considered invalid by the datetime.time module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `datetime.now` gives you a *date* and a *time*, whereas `time.fromisoformat` wants a *time* string only.

From the `time.fromisoformat` documentation:

> **Caution**
>
> This does not support parsing arbitrary ISO 8601 strings. It is only intended as the inverse operation of `time.isoformat()`.

Try again with

`datetime.now().time()` instead.

Answer (score 3):

You're using [`time.fromisoformat`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.time.fromisoformat), which only handles time strings. To parse a full datetime, use [`datetime.fromisoformat`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromisoformat):

```
>>> from datetime import datetime, time

# Bad
>>> time.fromisoformat(datetime.now().isoformat())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: Invalid isoformat string: '2021-09-02T17:31:25.857666'

# Good
>>> datetime.fromisoformat(datetime.now().isoformat())
datetime.datetime(2021, 9, 2, 17, 31, 43, 685120)
```